# where add cv2.resize to get appropriate resolution?

Tags: python, opencv, resolution

I have a problem with my code. I don't know where I could put `cv.resize()` in order to get requirement resolution. I want to change it because the file which I upload is full HD resolution and I want to get smaller resolution. I will be glad of solution and explanation.

Below I show my code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('DJI_0037.MP4')

while cap.isOpened():

    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if ret == True:
        frame_resize = cv2.resize(frame, (640, 480), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    else:
        break

    ret, frame_resize1 = cap.read(frame_resize)
    ret, frame_resize2 = cap.read(frame_resize)  

    diff = cv2.absdiff(frame_resize1, frame_resize2) 
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) 
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)  
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    dilated = cv2.dilate(thresh, None, iterations=3)
    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(dilated, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    for contour in contours: 
        (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)  
        if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 2000:
            continue
        cv2.rectangle(frame_resize1, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.putText(frame_resize1, "Status: {}".format('Movement'), (10, 20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0, 0, 255),3) 



    cv2.imshow("feed", frame_resize1)
    frame_resize1 = frame_resize2
    ret, frame_resize2 = cap.read()

    if cv2.waitKey(40) == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: either before absdiff (for both frames) or before imshow. Depending on what you want to do (save processing time and reduced quality or just better displaying)

Comment: Thank you very much for simple and clever explanation. Now, it works very well